# Php array Looping and calculate the average

Tags: php

I want to calculate the average of all the values of array based on key.
i have an array like this

```
$res_arr = 
array 
{
array[0]=>array
{
    [0] => 3
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 9
            [3] =>3
            [4] => 22
}
array[1]=>array
{
    [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 9
            [4] => 0
}
array[2]=>array
{
    [0] => 10
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 3
}
....
....
....
....
array[100]
}
```

There are totally 5 elements in each array

it should return an array with average calculated as

```
$av_array = ();
$array  = array(6,5.6,8.3,6.3,8.3)
```

Below is the loop i used

```
foreach($res_arr as $m=>$val)
{
    //echo $val[0];
    $return[$val[$m]][] = $val;
    //$cnt++;

}
```

Comment: What problem you face in above loop?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map) and [`array_sum`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
function array_average($arr)
{
  return array_sum($arr)/count($arr);
}

$array = array_map("array_average", $input_array);
print_r($array);
```

**Update:** Alternative syntax:

```
$array_average = function($arr) {
    return array_sum($arr)/count($arr);
};
$array = array_map($array_average, $input_array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Should `$array_average` be `"array_average"`?

Comment: @Class, yes, thanks for catching that, corrected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$av_array = [];
foreach($res_arr as $val)
{
    $av_array[] = array_sum($val)/count($val);
}
var_dump($av_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way..

```
foreach($arr as $arr1)
    {
        foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v)
        {
            $sum_arr[]=$v;
        }
        echo $avg = array_sum($sum_arr)/count($sum_arr);
        unset($sum_arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: No thats wrong ,it should returm single array like this
$array  = array(6,5.6,8.3,6.3,8.3)
3+5+10/3 = 6.5 Ele,emt by element

Comment: Like what ? Do you want the averages in an array or you want it as an output ?